# Drawing a chart from a sas dataset using third party libraries such as canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, sas

I must draw a pie chart from a sas table ,which I created, using third party libraries. I want to draw using canvas but I am open to any recommendation.
How can I handle this? I have no idea how to connect sas data table and html file which includes canvas.

Comment: Is this from SAS or are you using a different application to code here? Any reason to not just use the SAS graphs?

Answer (score 1):

SAS is ODBC compliant. Download the SAS ODBC driver for SAS datasets, read it in that way and use whatever graphics tool you have (Dundas, ComponentOne, Telerik, etc.). If using C#, just map it to a DataTable and bind.

Comment: Canvas is JavaScript.

Comment: Same concept even in JS. Should be fine. I assume server-side barring more info.

Answer (score -1):

Export Sas to .csv

Using this https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/create-charts-from-csv/

To know how pass your csv

In its example

$.get("https://canvasjs.com/services/data/datapoints.php?xstart=5&ystart=10&length=10&type=csv"<<<<<------this instead by your file save place

And See the demo https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/

It's fastest , i can image